# Extending arrays in parent theme without completely overriding the files

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I am new to all child-theming things and trying to override an array value which is declared in one of the php files. I also don't want to override the whole php file, because it has many other functions in that file that I don't want to duplicate.

How can I do this?

The `maintemplate-somefile.php` :

```
...

$Icons = array(
....
);

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how your themes-- parent and child-- are constructed but [the child theme's `functions.php` loads before the parent's](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php). So, if this template is included via `functions.php` changes you attempt to make in the child `functions.php` to that `$Icons` array will be overwritten as soon as the parent `function.php` loads. Since you say this has "many other functions", it seems likely that this file is somehow included from `functions.php`.

In fact, if `maintemplate-somefile.php` is included by any file that `$Icons` array will be overwritten, as per the code you posted there is no attempt to merge that array with pre-existing values.

If this is a page template, and you provide a replace template, the parent template will not load at all.

Your parent theme might have provided a hook that you could use, or there may be some other way to achieve the end you want, but given that you posted effectively no code it is hard to say much more.